# Logging with google acount in Flask

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, openid

I'm starting a web project (in flask) in which the user needs to authenticate with his google account to later save data files in his Google Drive using [PyDrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive)

Flask has a few libraries to authenticate but reading their doc, not all of them support OAuth2. The following 2 libraries DO support Oauth2 though.

- [Flask-OpenID](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OpenID/)
- [Flask-GoogleLogin](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-GoogleLogin/)

My question is, what is the best form to authenticate the google account? Or there is some extension for Google to make an even easier logging?